# Some inequality I stumbled upon, $b^3-a^2b+2a \geq 0$

Tags: inequality, functional-inequalities

$b^3-a^2b+2a \geq 0$

Given: $(a,b) \in \mathbb{N}$ and a>b.
Find when this holds.
This is an inequality I stumbled upon while I was surfing, and like any other day, I sat down trying to think about it. In general, playing with it gives me that $b \geq 3$ "guarantees" no value of $a$. Although proving the statement formally seems to take me forever. Initially, I tried to bring it to quadratic form in $a$, and if $b$ behaves like a constant, then we can see $P(a) \geq 0$ which imposes $D \leq 0$, but that implies $b^4+1 \leq 0$ which is absurd in the field we are working on. This somehow convinced me to try working on the cubic which doesn't seem to be factorizable either.

I would love a solution that could include the remedy and why my approach didn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to prove that $f(a)=b^3-a^2b+2a$ is a decreasing function of $a$.

Comment: Ok @youthdoo so since $f'(a)=2-2ab$ and $(a,b) \in \mathbb{N}$ this implies $f'(a)<0$ thus the function is decreasing. Can you tell me how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, for the error in your reasoning:

Note that (with $b$ fixed) solving for $P(a) \geq 0 $ does not impose $ D \leq 0$.
That is true only if $P(a) \geq 0 $ for all values of $a$ (which the problem doesn't require).
In this case, substantiated by your observation that $ D = 1+b^4 > 0 $, we know that for each $b$, there will be some positive and negative values of $P(a)$.
To find which are the valid $a$ values, we have to find the roots of the quadratic equation. This is essentially shown by Prasiortle.

---

Now, for a quick solution:

Write the inequality as $ \frac{2}{b} \geq \frac{ a^2 - 1}{a}$.
Observe that for $ a \geq 2$, we always have $ a < a^2 - 1$.
Hence, for this inequality to hold true, we must have $ \frac{2}{b} \geq \frac{ a^2 -1 }{ a} > 1 $, or that $ b =1$.
Thus, this gives us $ 2a \geq (a^2 -1 )$, or that $ a = 2$.

---

Now, for my original solution using a different method.

Let $ a = b + k$ where $ k$ is a positive integer.

Then the inequality becomes

$$ 2b + 2k \geq 2b^2k + bk^2. $$

From here, since

- $2b < bk^2$ except when $ k = 1$
- $2k \leq 2b^2k$

It follows that we must have $k = 1$.  This then gives us

$$2b + 2 \geq 2b^2 + b $$

and solving the quadratic shows us that the only positive integer solution is $ b = 1$.

Hence, the only solution is $ (a, b) = (2, 1)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out my original mistake. I really wanted that :)

Comment: Also this solution is quite unique and feels natural as well.

Comment: @TheRevolution My approach gets rid of the cubic term, which is why I chose it. $\quad$ Another way of writing it (which I've just added) is that we want $ 2a \geq b (a^2 - 1) $ ,and since $ a < a^2 - 1$ for $ a \geq 2$, we must have $ 2 > b \Rightarrow b = 1$.

Answer (score 4):

With $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a > b$, the only solution is $a = 2, b = 1$. To prove this, we rewrite the inequality as $$ba^2-2a-b^3 \leq 0,$$ with $a^2$ coefficient $b$, which is positive, and discriminant $4\left(b^4+1\right)$, which is also positive. Thus the solution over $\mathbb{R}$ is $$\frac{2-2\sqrt{b^4+1}}{2b} \leq a \leq \frac{2+2\sqrt{b^4+1}}{2b},$$ i.e. $$\frac{1-\sqrt{b^4+1}}{b} \leq a \leq \frac{1+\sqrt{b^4+1}}{b}.$$ Imposing the constraints $a > b$ and $a \in \mathbb{N}$, we require there to be an integer strictly greater than $b$ and less than or equal to $\frac{1+\sqrt{b^4+1}}{b}$. Since $b$ itself is a positive integer, this means the latter must be at least $b+1$, so $$\begin{align*}\frac{1+\sqrt{b^4+1}}{b} \geq b+1 &\iff 1+\sqrt{b^4+1} \geq b^2+b \qquad \text{(as } b > 0 \text{)} \\ &\iff \sqrt{b^4+1} \geq b^2+b-1.\end{align*}$$ If $b^2+b-1 \leq 0$, then this will automatically be true; but it's easily checked that there is no such $b \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, both sides will necessarily be positive, so we can square both sides to give $$\begin{align*}&b^4+1 \geq b^4+2b^3-b^2-2b+1 \\ &\iff 2b^3-b^2-2b \leq 0 \\ &\iff 2b^2-b-2 \leq 0 \qquad \text{(as } b > 0 \text{)} \\ &\iff \frac{1-\sqrt{17}}{4} \leq b \leq \frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{4} \\ &\iff b = 1 \qquad \text{(as } b \in \mathbb{N} \text{)}.\end{align*}$$ Finally, setting $b = 1$ in the original inequality yields $$\begin{align*}a^2-2a-1 \leq 0 &\iff 1-\sqrt{2} \leq a \leq 1+\sqrt{2} \\&\iff a \in \{1,2\} \qquad \text{(as } a \in \mathbb{N} \text{)}\end{align*}$$ but since $a > b$, only $a = 2$ is a valid solution, completing the proof.

Comment: That is really elegant I must say (in the sense that no advanced stuff was used) and pretty much every step explains itself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're very welcome! It's indeed the case that with polynomial inequalities in only $2$ variables, you generally don't need any advanced techniques. In this case it was particularly nice as the highest power of $a$ in any of the terms was $a^2$, so, with it being quadratic, there were straightforward expressions for the roots. If it was e.g. $a^3b$ instead, then you'd need to use calculus, along the lines of what the commenter above suggested.

Comment: As an aside, you can greatly simplify the work by observing that $(1+ \sqrt{b^4 + 1) } / b <   ( 1 + b^2 + 1/(2b^2) ) / b   $. The RHS is clearly  $ < b+1$ EXCEPT when $ b =1$. Hence, we must have $b =1 $, and subsequently show that $ a = b+1$.  $\quad$ This in part explains why you and I end up with the same $ 2b^2 - b - 2 \leq 0 $ inequality.

Comment: AMGM isn't involved. Just 1/ Binomial theorem $1+b^4 < [ b^2 + 1/(2b^2) ]^2$ and 2/ Comparing terms: (1+1/(2b^2) ) < 2 $.

Comment: Ah, yes, my mistake.